# Can someone retake a denied medical?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

If someone gets a denial on their medical or gets deferred but never follows up with the appointments, can they retake it at a later time?

For example, if someone gets denied on their medical and they want to retake the exam 10 years later will the original denial prevent them from passing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my personal experience having nearly lost my medical: If you are in the U.S., you will have to check the box on the application stating that your medical has been denied in the past. You will have to check that box every time you apply in the future. Having nearly had my medical denied in the past, my advice is to 1) find the most senior AME in your area and schedule an appointment for consultation. Explain your situation and take his/her advice. 2) Follow through on that advice (I had to see a well-regarded neurologist for a few hours' worth of exams and interrogation). Bring those results/reports with you to your next AME visit and have him/her send them to the FAA with your next medical application. The FAA's medical office in Oklahoma City will review your case and most likely send you a letter. I was able to get a medical issued the day I applied, however, the letter I received from OK City put me on a six month schedule before the age of 40. I strongly urge you to consult with the most senior AME you can find.

tl;dr - If you have been previously denied. You will have to provide documentation to your AME to overturn the denial.

Caveat: I am only familiar with the U.S./FAA system as a pilot.

[ I'll try to tidy this up when I get home later today ]

Comment: My experience is, if you come to a medical examinator with any condition, he will usually want to consult it with any more senior one and having multiple papers from specialists confirming the condition is not limiting much

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.  The condition, if you still have it, that caused the denial may have been subject to policy changes that have eased the impact of the policy.  Once upon a time you were permanently grounded with high blood pressure, now, not if it is controlled with approved medications, and the cutoff is higher.  Same with Type 2 diabetes.  Same with some types of arrhythmias.

In Canada they are now allowing airline pilots to fly (yes, restricted Cat 1 medicals) with (carefully controlled and monitored, with tight restrictions) Type 1 diabetes.  I knew a manufacturer exp test pilot who was allowed to fly with Parkinsons by demonstrating competency in front of his doctor in the Sim until the tremors got too severe and he had to retire.  I know of an airline pilot who was signed off to fly with one eye.

There is way more discretion in medical issues now. Retake the exam and see what happens.